# Issue With Active Directory objectClass

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I am trying to setup WebADM to use two factor authentication with a VPN tunnel. I managed to get this all working last week however there is a slight issue. WebADM will detect registered users by checking in the objectClass attribute of Active Directory for a value of webadmAccount. I managed to get this working by making it search for the value "user" instead, which obviously registered all my users to be able to use this, however I do want to be able to control who can access the VPN.

So the problem seems to be in adding a value to the objectClass of a user. If I attempt to manually add the class created by WebADM or ones created by myself, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------
ADSIEdit 
---------------------------
Operation failed. Error code: 0x2040
The specified method is not supported.


00002040: SvcErr: DSID-030F0E51, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Even if I try to add inetOrgUser to a users objectClass I will get exactly the same error. Googling around has not shed much light on this issue, so I am hoping someone can help me out here.

The DC was originally 2000 -> 2003 -> 2008 (current version)

Comment: Can you run the AD Schema Management MMC snapin, and get screen shots of the webadmAccount objectClass?  Include the tabs: General, Relationship, and Attributes.

Comment: Here you go: http://imgur.com/bhhO6qD,nobIbnL,9iG0fEh#0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I was aware, being able to change objectClass's only became available in 2008.

After banging my head against a wall with this problem for a few days, I checked the Forest Functional Level and it was still set at 2000.

Changing this by:

1. Opening Active Directory Domains and Trusts
2. Right clicking on Active Directory Domains and trusts in the left hand menu.
3. Select Raise forest functional level.
4. Make sure this is set >2003, if not, upgrade it.

After the upgrade, everything works fine.